# Swift access enum param

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I have this function:

```
@objc(syncUser:rejecter:)
  func syncUser(resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock, reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) {
    self.cancelableSyncUser = MyService.shared?.syncingUser()
      .sink(receiveCompletion: {
        switch $0 {
        case .failure(let error):
          print("PRINT \(error)")
          reject(error.localizedDescription, error.localizedDescription, error);
        case .finished:
          
        }
      }, receiveValue: {
        resolve($0);
      })
  }
```

I get an `error` object that contains some information that I want to use, but I cannot access its properties (code and message).

If I print the `error` object, I get this:

```
PRINT syncUser(Optional(mydomain.OpenpathErrorData(err: mydomain.OpenpathErrorData.Err(message: "Error message", code: "X"))), nil)
```

As we can see, it contains `code` and `message`.

`OpenpathErrorData` is an `enum` defined in another class:

```
  enum OpenpathError: Error {
    case syncUser(OpenpathErrorData?, Error?)
  }
```

```
struct OpenpathErrorData: Codable {
  struct Err: Codable {
    var message:String
    var code:String
  }
  var err: Err
}
```

The problem is that I cannot access those properties. I can only access `error.localizedDescription`.

I've tried everything but either I cannot access it or I don't know the right syntax.

Any ideas? I know it's hard to understand without seeing the whole code but if it's about the syntax maybe someone can give me a hint.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `if case ...` to access the content of the error structure.

```
if case let OpenpathError.syncUser(errorData, otherError) = error
```

With this we check if `error` is of the case `.synchUser` and at the same time we also assign the associated values of the enum case to the two (optional) variables `errorData` and `otherError` that you can then use in your code.

```
if case let OpenpathError.syncUser(errorData, otherError) = error {

    if let errorData = errorData {
        print(errorData.err.message, errorData.err.code)
    }

    if let otherError = otherError {
        print(otherError)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, you saved my life! i wish i could give you 20 points. thanks, i really appreciate your help :)